# Writing multiline JTextArea to txt file

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, filewriter, stringbuffer

so I Have a `JTextArea` for user input and then when they click a button it writes it to a text file, I have both `setLineWrap` and `setWrapStyleWord` set to `true` for the `JTextArea`.

I would like to write to the text file the exact way it appears in the text box.

I have tried to do a `replace("\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"))` on the `String` holding the contents of the `JTextArea` which works, but only if the user actually hits the return key when typing the input, but if the user just keeps typing and hits the end of a line so it jumps to the line below it, the `replace` doesnt work.

I have also tried using a `StringBuffer`, I calculated how many characters would fit in on line and then ran a `for loop` `inserting` new lines at the end of each line so for the first line I would add it at position `90`, 2nd line at `180`, third at `270` and so on. But I soon realized that does not work in all situations because some characters are smaller than others for example you could fit more `j`'s on a single line than `p`'s.

What I would like to do is just figure out a way calculate the end of a line so I know where to `insert` the new line, but I am open to other suggestions as well. Thanks. If you think it would help to see some of my code just ask.

**Update**
Instead of implementing code to do this, I talked to the person who will be pretty much one of the only people using this program and he was fine with regular notepad format and I didnt realize it but as long as he has wordWrap checked in his notepad format settings then that will eliminate him having to use the side scroll in order to read the entire line, Thanks for your input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Utilities`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Utilities.html) class

```
public static final int getRowStart(JTextComponent c, int offs)
public static final int getRowEnd(JTextComponent c, int offs)
```

you pass offset and get offset of the row start and end

Comment: You'll still need to iterate over the text area's string, though, to find where all the breaks are, right? (While I don't think this is an appropriate thing to do in this situation, that'd be a handy utility anyway, returning a collection of start/end pairs.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how, except to just calculate word lengths using font metrics and do what the text area already does.

What's the purpose behind this, though?

Comment: well the program as a whole does a lot more than this, the JTextArea is just a field for the user to enter notes but I'd like the notes to look nicely formatted in the notepad file, because I dont like how long lines can be in notepad requiring you to scroll sideways before reading the entire line, Im hoping the user would probably make his notes using bullets or something so it would just be a short bit of text before user hits return but I cant be sure of that

Comment: @Beef Notepad does word wrap too. The problem is when you add something like newlines, you're *forcing* your width: if they *want* it to be long in notepad, it'll be cut off to your text field's size. IMO you're better off storing as-is and letting the user decide.